# Failure in apt-get in 14.10

Tags: apt

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
....

Answer (score 0):

14.10 is now EOL. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Consider upgrading to 15.10 instead of trying to keep going after EOL.

One might suggest that non LTS releases have a ridiculously short lifetime (9 months feels short to me), but it's a tradeoff.  You get the latest/greatest, but have to upgrade more often :)